# MVC 3 Can't pass string as a View's model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a strange problem with my model passed to the View

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Sth()
{
    return View("~/Views/Sth/Sth.cshtml", "abc");
}
```

**View**

```
@model string

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "lorem";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Default.cshtml";
}
```

**The error message**

```
The view '~/Views/Sth/Sth.cshtml' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Sth/Sth.cshtml
~/Views/Sth/abc.master  //string model is threated as a possible Layout's name ?
~/Views/Shared/abc.master
~/Views/Sth/abc.cshtml
~/Views/Sth/abc.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/abc.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/abc.vbhtml
```

Why can't I pass a simple string as a model ?

Comment: Why are you using those relative paths? use this: `View("Sth", null, "abc");`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Yes you can if you are using the right [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492244.aspx):

```
return View("~/Views/Sth/Sth.cshtml" /* view name*/, 
            null /* master name */,  
            "abc" /* model */);
```

Comment: Alternative solution: `return View("~/Views/Sth/Sth.cshtml", model: "abc")`

Comment: Another Solution: return View("~/Views/Sth/Sth.cshtml", (object)"abc")

Comment: `return View("Sth", model: "abc");`

Answer (score 96):

If you use named parameters you can skip the need to give the first parameter altogether

```
return View(model:"abc");
```

or

```
return View(viewName:"~/Views/Sth/Sth.cshtml", model:"abc");
```

will also serve the purpose.

Answer (score 18):

You meant this `View` overload:

```
protected internal ViewResult View(string viewName, Object model)
```

MVC is confused by this overload:

```
protected internal ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName)
```

Use this overload:

```
protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName,
                                           Object model)
```

This way:

```
return View("~/Views/Sth/Sth.cshtml", null , "abc");
```

By the way, you could just use this:

```
return View("Sth", null, "abc");
```

[Overload resolution on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Now I see, I was using the constuctor `string viewName, object model`

Comment: @Tony. You meant `method` not constructor I guess. And the `Overload resolution` Got the wrong method(for you...)

Comment: Even just typecasting the string to object would probably have helped the overload resolution: `return View("Sth", (object) "abc");`, but calling the method `View(string, string, object)` is definitely clearer, in either case.

Comment: @OwenBlacker. I thought the same thing, but it will cause problem as the view expecting a `string` not an `object` as a model. so it will pass only stage one and then fail.

Comment: @gdoron Ah, that would make sense. Using the `View(string, string, object)` overload, as you mentioned in your answer, certainly seems like The Right Answer™, any any case.

Answer (score 5):

It also works if you pass null for the first two parameters:

```
return View(null, null, "abc");
```

Answer (score 4):

It also works if you declare the string as an object:

```
object str = "abc";
return View(str);
```

Or:

```
return View("abc" as object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You also write like

```
return View(model: "msg");
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems so pretty obvious but maybe someone needs more clarification in the future:

If in your controller do:

```
  string id = "abc";
  return View(model: id);
```

Then in your view, you need:

```
@model string
```

In order to get the value, for e.g.:

```
<div>@Model</div>
```